# Market volume to use Coppock Indicator as a entry signal for large volume stocks?

Tags: stock-markets, technical-analysis

I use the [Coppock Indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppock_curve) on indices as an indicator with other tools, to determine an entry point into a market, then once the Coppock has indicated entry then selecting stocks using other mechanisms.

It is well known that Coppock is best used on indexes with large volumes, like the FTSE, S&P500 and ASX200, I'm dubious it would work for smaller indices like the Ljubljanska borza.

I was wanting to extend the use of it to larger stocks like BHP.ax, TLS.ax, BA.uk, LGEN.uk, etc.

Has there been any research done on the "market value" or some other metric of "market size" that shows when Coppock is useful or not for this purpose?

Comment: You use it from time to time? You should either use it all the time or never! I wouldn't trade stocks with low volume anyway, I put a filter to only select stocks with average daily volume of over 100,000. And it says it is used on idexes not on individual stock as an indication of direction, I have seen someone use the ROC indicator in a similar way in a couple of questions on this site.

Comment: Yes, it is meant to be used on indexes, which I do, and generally works well for large indices like the FTSE, S&P500 and ASX200, I'm dubious it would work for smaller indices like the Ljubljanska borza. I was wanting to extend the use of it to larger stocks like BHP, TLS, etc. I will rephrase my question to clarify what I'm asking ...

Comment: You could backtest it (I would personally not rely on an indicator that I have not thoroughly backtested beforehand).

Comment: Indeed. Backtesting is critical!